# Calling many web services asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I need to process a bunch of completed orders (thousands). To make it faster, I'm using a `SemaphoreSlim` to schedule a number of orders to be processed in parallel. Every order goes through multiple web service calls to various APIs (SOAP, REST). Then I need to take the returned data and process it into a PDF. Here is what I am doing currently (note that this is in an ASP.NET app):

```
private async Task ProcessOrders(List<Orders> orders)
{
    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 5);

    foreach (var order in orders.Where(x => !x.HasError))
    {
        // do an async wait until we can schedule again
        await throttler.WaitAsync();

        // using Task.Run() to run the lambda in its own parallel
        // flow on the thread pool
        allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Call external web service here
                // Build order report PDF here
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }
        }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
}
```

However, I'm new to TPL and I don't know if this is the right way to do something like this. If it's relevant, this app is hosted on Amazon's AWS cloud.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not all that familiar with `async`/`await` (I *really* need to get going on this), but I find your code pretty clear, except why the magic number  `5` is being used for an `initialCount`.

I like your usage of `var`, but the comments are a little redundant, they say nothing much that the code doesn't already tell.

It would have been nice to see the actual code in place of the placeholder comments in the `try` block - I'd expect to see a method call here; if that comment stands for code that actually implements what's described, you need to factor it out.

Also I would have indented the async task's body, but that's more of a nitpick.

I would probably also have introduced a `var validOrders = orders.Where(order => !order.HasError);` to make the `foreach` loop clearer. Not sure I like `x` for a name in the lambda: try to use meaningful names *everywhere*.

Comment: I'm soon going to be learning C#, could you explain a little as to why use `var` is good versus using the actual class?

Comment: It is *exactly* the **same** as using the "actual" class; the only difference is readability. `var` is neither good or bad *in itself*, but should be avoided when the type isn't obvious and can't be inferred from the assignment, like `var foo = Bar();` vs `var foo = new Bar();`.

Comment: Thanks for the review. The 5 is just a placeholder for now—I still need to profile the code to find which initial count works best for my use case.

Answer (score 6):

`SemaphoreSlim` implements `IDisposable` and should be disposed of, preferably using the `using` statement.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the lambda you're passing to `Task.Run` is `async`, along with the comment, implies that the work being done is not CPU bound work, but rather is IO bound work.  Given this, there is no need to call `Task.Run` here.

`Task.Run` allows you to turn synchronous CPU bound work into asynchronous CPU bound work.  However, the work that you have is neither synchronous nor is it CPU bound.

The change is as simple as removing the call to `Task.Run`. This will remove the unneeded overhead of scheduling the IO operation on a thread pool thread without any loss of functionality.

---

An unrelated refactor that you could make is to use LINQ to transform your sequence of items into a sequence of tasks representing the completion of some work on those items, rather than creating a list, iterating the items, and adding the appropriate `Task` to the list.

Combining both refactors this gives us:

```
private async Task ProcessOrders(List<Orders> orders)
{
    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 5);

    var tasks = orders.Where(order => !order.HasError)
        .Select(async order =>
        {
            await throttler.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                await ProcessOrder(order);
            }
            finally
            {
                throttler.Release();
            }
        });

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a lot simpler (I'm impressed), but for some reason it's much slower than what I have now. Maybe it's the `await throttler.WaitAsync()` in the `Select()`?

Comment: You'd have to profile the code to see what's different.

Answer (score 3):

I think that "asynchronous foreach with limited degree of parallelism" is general enough for a helper method. With that, your code could look something like:

```
private async Task ProcessOrders(List<Orders> orders)
{
    await AsyncParallel.ForEach(
        orders.Where(x => !x.HasError), 5,
        async order =>
        {
            // Call external web service here
            // Build order report PDF here
        });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the task factory for this, as shown below.

```
private void ProcessOrders(List<Orders> orders)
{
    var allTasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var order in orders.Where(x => !x.HasError))
    {
        allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           // process order    
        ));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: 1. I think that just giving an alternative without explaining the differences is useless. 2. This wouldn't work correctly (but it would compile, which makes it especially dangerous), because the lambda is `async` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()` doesn't support that, whereas `Task.Run()` does.